# Can a web developer be accountable for text content that a copywriter has created?

Tags: software-development, job-description, websites

I work at a design agency and a copywriter wrote a copy document to populate a website. I uploaded it onto the site after skimming through for any grammatical errors but I didn't really digest the content.

The copywriter believes it is my job to also read, understand and check the copy as I add it. I'm happy to voice my opinions if I spot anything as I'm adding it, but I trust that what they have written is sufficient.

What do you think - should that be part of a developers criteria for payment?

Comment: It seems like a question for your manager. The requirements can certainly vary between companies and even teams or individuals. If you want to remove yourself from the situation, how about creating a process to allow others to add data themselves? That way you never directly interact with the data and it's much less likely for someone to hold you responsible if something's wrong.

Comment: “read, understand and check the copy” That seems to describe a copywriter’s position perfectly.  It seems like the real problem is the knowledgeable people in your organization have no part in what’s being written.  The copywriter job is to make sure the sentences are grammatically correct.  Which likely was the correct but if the gadget is green instead of red, the copywriter won’t pick up on that mistake, only the gadget designers would pick up on a mistake like that.

Comment: Ask the copywriter to review some HTML.

Comment: Put on hold as company-specific. General best practices if you're a freelance developer should be asked on [freelancing.se] if anywhere. Otherwise you should check with your manager where your responsibilities begin and end.

Answer (score 6):

That particular task is for a trained proof-reader - which most developers aren't.

If there is no proof-reader, then the final arbiter should be the client; it shouldn't be published on the site until they're happy with it. If they agree to it being published, then they're stating that it's as grammatically correct as they need it to be.

Also; if you're a developer, you're not a data-entry clerk. It's your job to build the framework, not to sit there typing data into the site.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm happy to voice my opinions if I spot anything as I'm adding it, but I trust that what they have written is sufficient. What do people think - should that be part of a developers remit?

You can and should definitely read the text before posting it, in case it has some notorious error or grammatical/lexical mistakes that stand out (or maybe some odd characters that mess up with your webpage). However I agree with you, **it is the copywriter's job to write the text and guarantee its content**.

You do good on checking it for him/her, but it definitely is not your responsibility to do so, as you can't respond for any content and meaning mistakes that you can't possibly be expected to know.

You mention that *the copywriter believes this is your responsibility*, so I suggest you **politely ask your boss to clarify to you if this is part of your tasks** so the copywriter can also be aware of this work interaction of content posting and writing.

Answer (score 0):

> I work at a design agency and the copywriter wrote a copy document to
>   populate a website. I copied and pasted it into the site with a quick
>   skim read for any grammatical errors but I didn't really digest the
>   content.

Although it isn’t explicit in your job description, the time cost to read and try to understand might give you different perspectives on a given subject. At the same time, doing this task may increase your reading comprehension and communication skills in general. An overall net gain.

> The copywriter believes it is my job to also read, understand and
>   check the copy as I add it. I'm happy to voice my opinions if I spot
>   anything as I'm adding it, but I trust that what they have written is
>   sufficient.

Best to confirm if this is an explicit job function or just a favor for copywriters as a form of professional courtesy.

> What do people think - should that be part of a developers remit?

Debugging code is similar to copy editing copy. You have a topic you want to convey and you utilize a programming language (grammar) to string together subjects and actions to convey that information.

Often times I’ve met programmers who struggle in English not because of an inherent inability (like dyslexia) but because of the lack of practice they have in English. Engagement and persistence in even cursory levels of copy editing may improve your overall job skills and help you build a rapport with your team as a whole.